# Shouldn't tan(x) be a continuous function

Tags: trigonometry, continuity

If a 'function ' is continuous it must have its limit at $a$ equal to $f(a)$. 
Considering tan(x) one may say that it is continuous for its domain but not a continuous function for all real numbers $\mathbb{R}$.

But isn't saying that wrong?  Simply because if we take $\mathbb{R}$ as the input of our function our function is no longer a function because a function is defined when 'each' input value has a well defined output which is not the case for all inputs in $\mathbb{R}$. And thus our function is no more a function and we cannot say if it's a non-continuous 'function'

Comment: Obviously, a function may be continuous only in a point of its domain of definition. See [Tangent function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tangent.html) : it is not defined for e.g $\dfrac {\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 5):

The domain of the tangent function is $\mathbb{R}\setminus\left(\frac\pi2+\pi\mathbb{Z}\right)$ and it is continuous. Since, if $k\in\mathbb Z$, the limit $\lim_{x\to\frac\pi2+k\pi}\tan x$ doesn't exist (in $\mathbb R$), you cannot extend it to a continuous function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: It should be $\pi/2$, not $\pi$. Since $\sin(n\pi)=0$, $\cos(n\pi)=(-1)^n$, $\tan(n\pi)$ is well-defined.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You don't take the domain as "input". A function consists of the following information

- A set $X$ on which it is defined
- A set $Y$ where it maps to
- The information how a point $x\in X$ is mapped.

So for example you can define $\tan: (\pi/2,3\pi/2)\to \mathbb R, x\mapsto \tan(x)$ or, if you want to take the maximal domain, $$\tan: \bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb Z}(\pi(n+1/2),\pi(n+3/2))\to \mathbb R,\ x\mapsto \tan(x)$$ but $\tan$ just isn't defined in, for example $\pi/2$. So your saying that we can take $\tan$ with "input" all of the reals, is not correct.

Comment: So Can I finally say that tanx is continuous function and also it's anyhow not possible that tanx will be non-continuous.

Comment: Yes, $\tan$ is a continuous function. But only on $$\bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb Z}(\pi(n+1/2),\pi(n+3/2))$$ not on $\mathbb R$, since it is not defined on $\mathbb R$.